# How can I set csrfExpires time in cakePHP2?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, csrf, csrf-token

I want to overwrite `public $csrfExpires = '+30 minutes';` in SecurityComponent.php. I want to make the token expire after 14 minutes. 
So I have added the below code in my controller file.

```
if (isset($this->Security) && $this->action == 'myAction') {
        $this->Security->csrfExpires = '+14 minutes';
}
```

But this does not seems to be working. Is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the conditions are try and your update is actually executing?

Comment: yes. I have confirmed that. 
What is actually happening when the abobe code runs, I believe it will generate a new token key for the form, regardless of the page refresh/reload.Is that right?